# XFA Creating Multiple Instances of a Page with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, xfa

Looking at the USCIS form [N-400](http://www.uscis.gov/files/form/n-400.pdf), you can see that in Part 9 has two buttons, `Add Children` and `Go to continuation page` Looking at the XML/JS backing those buttons you get this node for the corresponding field:

```
<event activity="click" name="event__click">
    <script contentType="application/x-javascript">
        _KidsContPage.addInstance(1);
        xfa.form.recalculate(1);
        xfa.host.pageDown( );
    </script>
</event>
```

This is used to add the automatically hidden page to the form in case the user has more than 8 children. My question is using `iTextSharp`, or perhaps some other method, how do I create this new instance of the page? If you notice you can make multiple copies of this additional children page, if, somehow, you happen to have more than 25 kids, so not getting side-tracked by the unlikelihood of that possibility, I need to know how to create multiples of such a page...

This is what I have so far:

```
PdfAction cloneAction = PdfAction
    .JavaScript(ClonePage("KidsContPage"), stamper.Writer);
stamper.Writer.AddJavaScript(cloneAction);
```

I've also tried with SetOpenAction

```
stamper.Writer.SetOpenAction(cloneAction);


    private string ClonePage(string formName)
    {
        return @"
if (xfa.host.name != 'XFAPresentationAgent') {
    $._" + formName + @".addInstance(1);
    if (xfa.host.version < 8) {
        xfa.form.recalculate(1);
    }
}";
    }
```

I know that my `ClonePage()` code is being run, because I see the alert when I tested it earlier, the problem is in the javascript or perhaps I somehow need to run it at server or who knows what I need to do. I opened the `XFA PDF` in `LiveCycle` and that's the JS that it's putting out for it, I must be missing something small somewhere...and it works fine in LiveCycle. Please help.

Comment: Essentially you seem to hope to somehow make itext execute the Javascript action associated with that event. That won't happen because itext is no Javascript interpreter, let alone one with the special pdf and xfa API available in the Adobe Reader. This, you essentially have to compare the xfa Form xml before and after that script is executed and create a program that does the same changes on the xfa you extract using itext.

Comment: Ahh no. Perhaps you misunderstand. I do not need iText to interpret the JavaScript, just add it to the XFA document (which it is quite capable of doing as I personally tested it on things like `alert()`). The PDF will still be rendered in Adobe Reader... so your comment does not apply at all.

Comment: Ah, so your *question is* **not** *using iTextSharp, or perhaps some other method, how do* you *create this new instance of the page* but how to use it to **cause it to be created on the next opening** of the document in Acrobat Reader?

Comment: Right, that's correct